# How do you create a for loop with a changeable number of iterations?

Tags: bash, shell-script, for

How do you iterate through a loop n amount of times when n is specified by the user at the beginning?

I have written a shell script and need to repeat a certain part of it n numbers of times (depending upon how many times the user wishes).

My script so far looks like this:

```
echo "how many times would you like to print Hello World?"
read num
for i in {1.."$num"}
do
echo "Hello World"
done
```

If I change "num" to a number such as "5" the loop works however I need to be able to let the user specify the amount of times to iterate through the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `seq`

```
for i in $(seq 1 "$num")
```

or your shell may support C-style loops e.g. in bash

```
for ((i=0; i<$num; i++))
```

Comment: @Sofia And you can use simpler expression  `$(seq $num)`  instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo "how many times would you like to run your loop ?"
read  max

i=0
while [ "$((i+=1))" -le "$max" ]
do
   # whatever you want to do here
done
```

Comment: Why `${i}` and `${num}`? I think they should be `$i` and `$num`. Or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: curly brackets after $ sign is the proper way of addressing variables in bash or any modern shell. `$i` and `$num` can work under this circumstance but not enclosing the variables in curly brackets, sometimes yield unexpected results (not in this case of course). So it is a good practice, using them all the time to develop a good habit

Comment: I got it. Here is more about using curly braces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748831/bash-when-do-we-need-curly-braces-in-variables

Comment: The loop test fails on `max=''` (the user just press enter). A solution could be to just replace `"$max"` with `"$(( max ))"`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - it doesn't fail - it correctly doesn't loop and writes a descriptive message about why to stderr. Failure would be accepting `PATH=123`, which your thing might do in many shells.

Comment: The program stops running, thus, it's broken.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - no. the program requests input of a certain type, validates it as such, and acts accordingly. i think it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using "Arithmetic Evaluation" (bash only):

```
read -p "how many times would you like to print Hello World? " max

i=0
while  (( i++ < max ))
do
   echo "$i, Hello World."
done
```

Or use this if you want to make the program quite more robust.
This will extract only numbers from the input. Except for a very big number that could take a long time to be processed, any other input will be cleaned before its used.

```
while (( i++ < ${max//[^0-9]} ))
```

Comment: try feeding it `++i` or `(PATH=123)` or `IFS=0,PATH=123,++i`

Comment: If the input is not "of a certain type" and the program needs additional protection, use the *already* included  sanitizing expansion: `${max//[^0-9]}`

Comment: it wasn't already indicated... but it is good. it might do unexpected stuff if a user enters `476 843` and expects the input to be interpreted twice, i guess. it would also bug me if i were to give it something that was definitely not a number like *this isnt a number1* and it just went and ahead and used it anyway. but, at the least, it will probably not do much worse than that.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way with `{1.."$num"}`. Bash exapansion need to be evaluated before this can be transferred to the for loop. You can use expansion syntax this way to make it work :

```
for i in $(eval echo {1.."$num"}); 
do 
 echo $i; 
done
```

Comment: great, yet again someone silently downvoted.... why people ? I didn't say this is the best solution, but I would like to know what's wrong with the solution here !

Comment: It's not the best option to use `eval`, but I don't see anything wrong with this answer. BTW, it is worth noting, that in `zsh` one just can do `for i in {1..$num}`.

Comment: agreed. I just wanted to put this one out there that curly braces can be used with `eval`.